# Which Bitcoin exchanges publish proof of reserves?

Tags: exchanges, fractional-reserve

I am tired of fractional reserve exchanges continuing to run with account holders eventually holding the bag.

Which exchanges publish proof of reserves.

Real time proof with blockchain addresses would be best, but audited reports from a tech savvy accounting firm would be better than the status quo for most exchanges where no transparency is provided at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several exchanges have published reports (OKCoim, Kraken) but Bitfinex is the only one I am aware of to offer real time proof of reserves with individual BitGo wallets.

"The era of commingling customer Bitcoin and all of the associated security exposures is over"

http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20150603005462/en/Bitfinex-BitGo-Partner-Create-World%E2%80%99s-Real-Time-Proof

Implementation plans exist so maybe more exchanges will follow:
https://iwilcox.me.uk/2014/proving-bitcoin-reserves

Proof of Solvency appears to be a similar term used by the industry